# Regex for date format dd Mmm yyyy from email header

Tags: regex

I have the following regex that I have been working on:

`^(\d\d)\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s(\d{4})?$`

I am trying to grab the date from an email header that is formatted like so:

`"Mon, 18 Nov 2019 09:19:17 -0700 (MST)"`

and I want the result to be:

`18 Nov 2019`

It seems that the `\s` for whitespace could be the culprit, but I have yet to find another forum result that grabs dates with whitespace instead of `"-"` or `"/"`.

Does anyone have any suggestions for getting this working to extract as described above? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? You've described your expected output - what's the actual output you're getting?

Comment: This might be off topic but if you dont necessarily have to use regex to parse this. If you dont have to use regex, you could simply `split()` the string by white space and then pull the values that you want, as long as the input format is always the same.

Comment: @KevinHernandez that's the issue, the headers vary depending on origin client

Comment: @NickReed I'm not getting an output at all - no matches. Should have mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have added the "^" and "$" symbol on the start and end of the regex.

"^n": The ^n quantifier matches any string with n at the beginning of it.
"n$": The n$ quantifier matches any string with n at the end of it.

Since the text is not start with 2 digit (\d\d) and end with 2 digit (\d{4}). You will not get any result from this regex.

You can simply remove those two symbol or use the following code to achieve that.

```
/(\d{2}\s(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{4})/.exec("Mon, 18 Nov 2019 09:19:17 -0700 (MST)")[1]
```

Comment: yikes! leftovers from another test I was doing - thanks for this. Working now and relieved it was this simple of a fix.